# Deep learning model for extracting signal without noise

Tags: python, deep-learning, signal-processing

I have a problem defining a deep model for extracting the raw signals from noisy signals. I have signals that create using fECG + mECG + noise as ECG signal and I also have fECG signal separately. I want to use ECG signal for the train model and fECG for the label.
I use a sliding window to split the signal into 1000 samples. So my data and my label are (1000*1).
I cant find a good deep model to train this.
Can you help me?
[image]

This picture is ECG signal (fECG + mECG + noise)
[image]

This picture is fECG related to the above signal.
I code deep learning using Keras, python.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, you have a noisy signal (fECG + mECG + noise) and a corresponding clean signal (fECG). Now you want a model to extract the clean signal from the noisy one.

For this use case I would recommend a denoising autoencoder. You can find an explanation [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/denoising-autoencoders-explained-dbb82467fc2).